# Calling javascript function in Blazor for a Metronic Theme

Tags: c#, blazor

I have been trying for sometime now to call the functions to this wizard on click but to no avail. Once i step through the code it works. If i take off the breakpoints, nothing. I've tried different calls but nothing works if i don't step through. My knowledge on js is not really that good.
C# Code:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {

     await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("KTWizard", "goTo(number)");


    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
  // plugin setup
  var KTWizard = function(elementId, options) {
// Main object
var the = this;
var init = false;

// Get element object
var element = KTUtil.get(elementId);
var body = KTUtil.get('body');

if (!element) {
    return; 
}

// Default options
var defaultOptions = {
    startStep: 1,
    manualStepForward: false
};

////////////////////////////
// ** Private Methods  ** //
////////////////////////////

var Plugin = {
    /**
     * Construct
     */

    construct: function(options) {
        if (KTUtil.data(element).has('wizard')) {
            the = KTUtil.data(element).get('wizard');
        } else {
            // reset menu
            Plugin.init(options);

            // build menu
            Plugin.build();

            KTUtil.data(element).set('wizard', the);
        }

        return the;
    },

    /**
     * Init wizard
     */
    init: function(options) {
        the.element = element;
        the.events = [];

        // merge default and user defined options
        the.options = KTUtil.deepExtend({}, defaultOptions, options);

        // Elements
        the.steps = KTUtil.findAll(element, '[data-ktwizard-type="step"]');

        the.btnSubmit = KTUtil.find(element, '[data-ktwizard-type="action-submit"]');
        the.btnNext = KTUtil.find(element, '[data-ktwizard-type="action-next"]');
        the.btnPrev = KTUtil.find(element, '[data-ktwizard-type="action-prev"]');
        the.btnLast = KTUtil.find(element, '[data-ktwizard-type="action-last"]');
        the.btnFirst = KTUtil.find(element, '[data-ktwizard-type="action-first"]');

        // Variables
        the.events = [];
        the.currentStep = 1;
        the.stopped = false;
        the.totalSteps = the.steps.length;

        // Init current step
        if (the.options.startStep > 1) {
            Plugin.goTo(the.options.startStep);
        }

        // Init UI
        Plugin.updateUI();
    },

    /**
     * Build Form Wizard
     */
    build: function() {
        // Next button event handler
        KTUtil.addEvent(the.btnNext, 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            Plugin.goNext();
        });

        // Prev button event handler
        KTUtil.addEvent(the.btnPrev, 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            Plugin.goPrev();
        });

        // First button event handler
        KTUtil.addEvent(the.btnFirst, 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            Plugin.goFirst();
        });

        // Last button event handler
        KTUtil.addEvent(the.btnLast, 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            Plugin.goLast();
        });

        KTUtil.on(element, 'a[data-ktwizard-type="step"]', 'click', function() {
            var index = KTUtil.index(this) + 1;
            if (index !== the.currentStep) {
                Plugin.goTo(index);
            }                
        });
    },

    /**
     * Handles wizard click wizard
     */

        goTo: function (number) {
            // Skip if this step is already shown
            if (number === the.currentStep || number > the.totalSteps || number < 0) {
                return

            }

        // Validate step number
        if (number) {
            number = parseInt(number);
        } else {
            number = Plugin.getNextStep();
        }

        // Before next and prev events
        var callback;

        if (number > the.currentStep) {
            callback = Plugin.eventTrigger('beforeNext');
        } else {
            callback = Plugin.eventTrigger('beforePrev');
        }

        // Skip if stopped
        if (the.stopped === true) {
            the.stopped = false;
            return;
        }

        // Continue if no exit
        if (callback !== false) {
            // Before change
            Plugin.eventTrigger('beforeChange');

            // Set current step 
            the.currentStep = number;

            Plugin.updateUI();

            // Trigger change event
            Plugin.eventTrigger('change');
        }

        // After next and prev events
        if (number > the.startStep) {
            Plugin.eventTrigger('afterNext');
        } else {
            Plugin.eventTrigger('afterPrev');
        }

        return the;
    },

    /**
     * Cancel
     */
    stop: function() {
        the.stopped = true;
    },

    /**
     * Resume
     */
    start: function() {
        the.stopped = false;
    },

    /**
     * Check last step
     */
    isLastStep: function() {
        return the.currentStep === the.totalSteps;
    },

    /**
     * Check first step
     */
    isFirstStep: function() {
        return the.currentStep === 1;
    },

    /**
     * Check between step
     */
    isBetweenStep: function() {
        return Plugin.isLastStep() === false && Plugin.isFirstStep() === false;
    },

    /**
     * Go to the next step
     */
    goNext: function() {
       return Plugin.goTo(Plugin.getNextStep());
    },

    /**
     * Go to the prev step
     */
    goPrev: function() {
        return Plugin.goTo(Plugin.getPrevStep());
    },

    /**
     * Go to the last step
     */
    goLast: function() {
        return Plugin.goTo(the.totalSteps);
    },

    /**
     * Go to the first step
     */
    goFirst: function() {
        return Plugin.goTo(1);
    },

    /**
     * Go to the first step
     */
    updateUI: function() {
        var stepType = '';
        var index = the.currentStep - 1;

        if (Plugin.isLastStep()) {
            stepType = 'last';
        } else if (Plugin.isFirstStep()) {
            stepType = 'first';
        } else {
            stepType = 'between';
        }

        KTUtil.attr(the.element, 'data-ktwizard-state', stepType);

        // Steps
        var steps = KTUtil.findAll(the.element, '[data-ktwizard-type="step"]');

        if (steps && steps.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0, len = steps.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (i == index) {
                    KTUtil.attr(steps[i], 'data-ktwizard-state', 'current');
                } else {
                    if (i < index) {
                        KTUtil.attr(steps[i], 'data-ktwizard-state', 'done');
                    } else {
                        KTUtil.attr(steps[i], 'data-ktwizard-state', 'pending');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Steps Info
        var stepsInfo = KTUtil.findAll(the.element, '[data-ktwizard-type="step-info"]');
        if (stepsInfo &&stepsInfo.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0, len = stepsInfo.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (i == index) {
                    KTUtil.attr(stepsInfo[i], 'data-ktwizard-state', 'current');
                } else {
                    KTUtil.removeAttr(stepsInfo[i], 'data-ktwizard-state');
                }
            }
        }  

        // Steps Content
        var stepsContent = KTUtil.findAll(the.element, '[data-ktwizard-type="step-content"]');
        if (stepsContent&& stepsContent.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0, len = stepsContent.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (i == index) {
                    KTUtil.attr(stepsContent[i], 'data-ktwizard-state', 'current');
                } else {
                    KTUtil.removeAttr(stepsContent[i], 'data-ktwizard-state');
                }
            }
        }            
    },

    /**
     * Get next step
     */
    getNextStep: function() {
        if (the.totalSteps >= (the.currentStep + 1)) {
            return the.currentStep + 1;
        } else {
            return the.totalSteps;
        }
    },

    /**
     * Get prev step
     */
    getPrevStep: function() {
        if ((the.currentStep - 1) >= 1) {
            return the.currentStep - 1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    },

    /**
     * Trigger events
     */
    eventTrigger: function(name) {
        //KTUtil.triggerCustomEvent(name);
        for (var i = 0; i < the.events.length; i++) {
            var event = the.events[i];
            if (event.name == name) {
                if (event.one == true) {
                    if (event.fired == false) {
                        the.events[i].fired = true;
                        event.handler.call(this, the);
                    }
                } else {
                    event.handler.call(this, the);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    addEvent: function(name, handler, one) {
        the.events.push({
            name: name,
            handler: handler,
            one: one,
            fired: false
        });

        return the;
    }
};

//////////////////////////
// ** Public Methods ** //
//////////////////////////

/**
 * Set default options 
 */

the.setDefaults = function(options) {
    defaultOptions = options;
};

/**
 * Go to the next step 
 */
the.goNext = function() {
    return Plugin.goNext();
};

/**
 * Go to the prev step 
 */
the.goPrev = function() {
    return Plugin.goPrev();
};

/**
 * Go to the last step 
 */
the.goLast = function() {
    return Plugin.goLast();
};

/**
 * Cancel step 
 */
the.stop = function() {
    return Plugin.stop();
};

/**
 * Resume step 
 */
the.start = function() {
    return Plugin.start();
};

/**
 * Go to the first step 
 */
the.goFirst = function() {
    return Plugin.goFirst();
};

/**
 * Go to a step
 */
the.goTo = function(number) {
    return Plugin.goTo(number);
};

/**
 * Get current step number 
 */
the.getStep = function() {
    return the.currentStep;
};

/**
 * Check last step 
 */
the.isLastStep = function() {
    return Plugin.isLastStep();
};

/**
 * Check first step 
 */
the.isFirstStep = function() {
    return Plugin.isFirstStep();
};

/**
 * Attach event
 */
the.on = function(name, handler) {
    return Plugin.addEvent(name, handler);
};

/**
 * Attach event that will be fired once
 */
the.one = function(name, handler) {
    return Plugin.addEvent(name, handler, true);
};

// Construct plugin
Plugin.construct.apply(the, [options]);

return the;
```

};

Comment: If you are lucky enough only dani herrera  can help you with this. Good luck.

Comment: Hope whoever that is sees this. Thank you.

Comment: Did you have any joy getting the Metronic theme to work with Blazor?

Comment: I could not get it to work at full functionality but the little that did work was pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently struggling with this and found the solution after digging into the scripts.bundle.js file for the metronic theme.

To make metronic work in blazor, place all the js imports in index.html / _Host.cshtml file like normal.

The event listeners will not be added to DOM elements upon loading a page since the DOM is rendered after the js files. To fix this locate KTUtil.ready(function(){...}) in scripts .bundle.js file which you previously added as an import in index.html file.

Take the function mentioned inside KTUtil.ready() and define a js function. Then using JSInterop call that function in OnAfterRenderAsync on a page which uses metronic componenets. That function is responsible for initializing all the event handlers

This is the scripts.bundle.js function you have to define in a JS file

```
function() {
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Layout Base Partials(mandatory for core layout)//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Init Desktop & Mobile Headers
if (typeof KTLayoutHeader !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutHeader.init('kt_header', 'kt_header_mobile');
}

// Init Header Menu
if (typeof KTLayoutHeaderMenu !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutHeaderMenu.init('kt_header_menu', 'kt_header_menu_wrapper');
}

// Init Header Topbar For Mobile Mode
if (typeof KTLayoutHeaderTopbar !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutHeaderTopbar.init('kt_header_mobile_topbar_toggle');
}

// Init Brand Panel For Logo
if (typeof KTLayoutBrand !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutBrand.init('kt_brand');
}

// Init Aside
if (typeof KTLayoutAside !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutAside.init('kt_aside');
}

// Init Aside Menu Toggle
if (typeof KTLayoutAsideToggle !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutAsideToggle.init('kt_aside_toggle');
}

// Init Aside Menu
if (typeof KTLayoutAsideMenu !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutAsideMenu.init('kt_aside_menu');
}

// Init Subheader
if (typeof KTLayoutSubheader !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutSubheader.init('kt_subheader');
}

// Init Content
if (typeof KTLayoutContent !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutContent.init('kt_content');
}

// Init Footer
if (typeof KTLayoutFooter !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutFooter.init('kt_footer');
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Layout Extended Partials(optional to use)//
//////////////////////////////////////////////

// Init Scrolltop
if (typeof KTLayoutScrolltop !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutScrolltop.init('kt_scrolltop');
}

// Init Sticky Card
if (typeof KTLayoutStickyCard !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutStickyCard.init('kt_page_sticky_card');
}

// Init Stretched Card
if (typeof KTLayoutStretchedCard !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutStretchedCard.init('kt_page_stretched_card');
}

// Init Code Highlighter & Preview Blocks(used to demonstrate the theme features)
if (typeof KTLayoutExamples !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutExamples.init();
}

// Init Demo Selection Panel
if (typeof KTLayoutDemoPanel !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutDemoPanel.init('kt_demo_panel');
}

// Init Chat App(quick modal chat)
if (typeof KTLayoutChat !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutChat.init('kt_chat_modal');
}

// Init Quick Actions Offcanvas Panel
if (typeof KTLayoutQuickActions !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutQuickActions.init('kt_quick_actions');
}

// Init Quick Notifications Offcanvas Panel
if (typeof KTLayoutQuickNotifications !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutQuickNotifications.init('kt_quick_notifications');
}

// Init Quick Offcanvas Panel
if (typeof KTLayoutQuickPanel!== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutQuickPanel.init('kt_quick_panel');
}

// Init Quick User Panel
if (typeof KTLayoutQuickUser !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutQuickUser.init('kt_quick_user');
}

// Init Quick Search Panel
if (typeof KTLayoutQuickSearch !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutQuickSearch.init('kt_quick_search');
}

// Init Quick Cart Panel
if (typeof KTLayoutQuickCartPanel !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutQuickCartPanel.init('kt_quick_cart');
}

// Init Search For Quick Search Dropdown
if (typeof KTLayoutSearch !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutSearch().init('kt_quick_search_dropdown');
}

// Init Search For Quick Search Offcanvas Panel
if (typeof KTLayoutSearchOffcanvas !== 'undefined') {
    KTLayoutSearchOffcanvas().init('kt_quick_search_offcanvas');
}
```

}

And this is how you call it,

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("metronicScript");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("KTWizard.goTo", 2);
```

2 is basically the number you want to pass to JS, you also need to make sure that KTWizard is already declared and created part of window object, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm getting an unhandled exception error but if i click it a few times it goes to the next step.